# Basics in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am learning complex analysis and having doubts in the basics as follows:-

1. I read that the derivative of a complex valued function $f(z)$
   behaves exactly in the similar fashion as if it were a real valued
   function $f(x)$.I would like to know why that happens. If i guess
   that it is because the definition of differentiability in both the
   worlds, the complex as well as the real is $'identically'$ similar .
   If there's more to it ,please help me here.
2. The integral of a complex-valued function is defined along a contour as the sum of the product of the function value at $z$ times the displacement $dz$ .What does this represent if it's not area under the curve ? $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz .$$
3. Following from above ,in complex integrations , we essentially multiply two complex numbers (i.e. $f(z)$ and $dz$) , simplify them to a single number and then integrate. How is this action inside an integral is justifiable ?
4. In Cauchy's theorem of analytic functions in a simple closed curve , is it necessary to have
   function $f(z)$ being $'extending ...smoothly'$ towards the contour. Is it necessary as well as suffficient if the function is only analytic on and inside the contour and outside the contour it can behave in a rather funny way.Can that happen ?

***If there's some text that people here can share on complex analysis , that would be really helpful.***

Thanks for helping.

Comment: For #2: while area under a curve was a big motivation for defining (real-valued) integrals, the actual definition is a limit of Riemann sums. We then find that limits of Riemann sums come up in other contexts as well (such as finding volumes of solids of revolution), which reinforces the fact that integrals are really limits of Riemann sums, more fundamentally than they are areas. Contour integrals are simply limits of Riemann sums where the summands can be complex (which is also the answer to #3).

Comment: @GregMartin Sir, meaning the integrals came into picture as a special symbol just to evaluate limit of reimann sums and then we found out that they , in real world, gives area under the curve .this is quite remarkable .

Comment: the definition of the integral in the complex plane is namely $\int_{c} f(z)dz=\int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t)dt$, where $c$ parametrized by $z(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$, in my understanding this definition is special in the sense that we have cauchy theorems analogous to line integrals of vector fields

Comment: if however you expand $f$ as $f=u+iv$, in the integral definition, you get $\int_{c} f(z)dz=\int_{c}[u,-v]+i\int_{c}[v,u]$ so that the integral definition can be intuitively thought as the line integrals of the vector fields $[u,-v], [v,u]$ on the contour c

Comment: as for the motivation,  it is very clear that analytic functions satisfy a number of very fundamental properties and by using this definition the expression of such properties becomes very simple, as you can see from cauchy integral formula, or that functions that are holomorphic on a domain d are infinitely differentiable, such strong statement is derived from this definition.

Comment: @muhammad how about the fourth point . this term 'extending...smoothly' just outside the domain D of where an analytic function is defined in cauchy's theorem ?

Comment: as far as i know, the definition of the contour is that it is a "smooth arc" meaning that the derivative of the parametrization of such contour doesnt vanish, e.g $z'(t)\neq 0$, on the other hand cauchy theorem only demands that $f$ be analytic inside and on the contour c, it is irrelevant what happens outside the contour. as for contour itself, you can show that cauchy theorem still holds even if the curve intersects an infinite number of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the source of the problem is thinking about the integral primarily as "the area under a curve".  That's one *application* of integration, but it isn't what integration *is*.  Integration is the infinite sum of infinitely small values.  That's why complex integration works just like real integration.  $f(z)\,dz$ is just an infinitely small value that gets summed.  It works for multivariable equations just like single-variable equations.  It is literally just an infinite sum of infinitely small values.

The reason why, in the reals, it represents an area under a curve, is that if you divide the curve $f(x)$ into infinitely small rectangles, each rectangle will be $f(x)$ tall and $dx$ wide.  So, $\int f(x)\,dx$ is just the sum of all those areas.  But the function that the integration itself is performing is not area, but summation.  It doesn't matter to the integral that $f(x)\,dx$ represents an area or anything else.  Therefore, since addition works the same in the complex numbers as it does in the reals, integration also works the same, because it is just a summation.

If you realize that integration is just the infinite sum of infinitely small values, then I think that answers all of your questions, at least implicitly.

Comment: Sir , can you please share your insight on the fourth point.

Comment: 'If you realize that integration is just the infinite sum of infinitely small values'  - can we say that this is derived from integration being essentially limit of reimann sums ?

Answer (score 1):

Is this one question or four questions?

(1). The derivative of a complex function is not at all (other than superficially) like that of a real function.  For example, if a complex function has one derivative, it has infinitely many derivatives!

(2). A contour integral could represent various physical entities (for example work) depending on the context.  Green's theorem and Stokes' theorem relate a contour integral to an "area" or "volume" integral.  In any case, the integral needs no physical analogue.

(3).  The term $dz$ is a differential, similar to the role of differential in a real integral.

(4).  In Cauchy's theorem, $f(z)$ is holomorphic (it has a derivative).

Please read "Chapter zero" of Stein and Shakarchi, **Complex Analysis** for more motivation.

Comment: I am sorry. Thanks for mentioning the book.

Comment: No need to apologize.  You are welcome.